# How delete JPanel from JFrame before adding new one

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I have JPanel has already added to JFrame. And I have dynamically added JPanel. After adding JPanel on the fly it stay near the JPanel added before. How can I delete previous JPanel?

PS
I also think about using cardlayout - is it a good way?

Comment: Yes, [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) **is** a good way.

Comment: Yeah! I use it now. I do all I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method [`getComponents()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents%28%29) which will give you the child component in `JFrame`

you will use it like this way:

```
Component[] comp = frame.getContentPane().getComponents();
for(int i=0; i<comp.lenght; i++)
{
    if(comp[i] instanceof JPanel)
    {
        frame.remove(comp[i]);
    }
}
```

**Note:** this fix only works when you have single `JPanel` inside `JFrame` at a time, otherwise you gonna remove all your `JPanels` from `JFrame`.

Comment: thx! I will try it! I have some views extends JPanel class, so I think I can use "instanceof MyViewClass" to find necessary panel...

Comment: I also  tried to add all necessary panels on the same place and do show\hide operations. It's a better way than delete them each time. But panels dont lie one under another as I want. Can I do smth to make them lay one under another?

Comment: Use `BorderLayout`, all the `Components` will be added to center, if you use `add(comp)`. It will use hierarchy of FIFO.